# Some sort of border is surrounding my webpage while I am trying to make a parallax

Tags: html, css

I am having a problem with my webpage that I am in the prosses of making. [Here is the W3schools link to what I am trying to make.](https://easy-to-make-foods-breakfast--sour_tooth.repl.co/)

There's some sort of border around the edges of my webpage. Here is my CSS code:

```
#easyBreakfast {
color: #60542d;
font-size: 40px;
}

#head {
background-color: brown;
}

#p1 {
font-size: 20px;
margin: 8px;
}

body, html {
height: 100%;
}

.parallax { 

 background-image: url("https://i.pinimg.com/originals/4a/67/3b/4a673bea73e5130d5fb58e5904c76465.png");
height: 100%; 
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}

#toast { 
background-image: url("http://a57.foxnews.com/images.foxnews.com/content/fox-news/food-drink/2017/12/12/internet-is-divided-over-right-way-to-cut-toast/_jcr_content/par/featured_image/media-0.img.jpg/931/524/1513113018403.jpg?ve=1&tl=1&text=big-top-image");
height: 100%; 
}

#toast, .parallax {
position: relative;
opacity: 0.65;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-size: cover;
}
```

Here is my HTML code regarding this problem:

```
  <h1 id="easyBreakfast">Easy Breakfasts</h1>
    <p id="p1">You know when you wake up late in the morning and only have <em>15 minuites</em> to get ready? Sometimes making breakfast can be a <strong>pain.</strong> These recipes are quick and don't need attention while cooking so you can do your other important things while your breakfast is brewing.
    </p>
</div>    

  <div class="parallax"></div>

  <h2 class="fooditem"><a href=" ">Toast</a></h2>
    <p>Just plain old toast... Spread jam, Peanut butter, Nutella, or any other topping you can think of on top of this simple breakfast. </p>
      <button id="toastIng"> Ingredients </button>
  <div id="toast"></div>`
```

I have tried turning outline and border off, but I just can't seem to find a solution.

If you need any more information, just ask. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forgot to post the link to my webpage: https://easy-to-make-foods-breakfast--sour_tooth.repl.co/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a margin on your body.

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```